# Solr indexing slowdown

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm working on a product which index high volume of small documents.
When starting Solr it provide indexing rate of 35k/sec for around 20 minutes and then start to slowdown down to 24k/sec after a while.
If I restart the server, the server will index again 35k/sec for 20 minutes and then slow down again.
I have a softCommit every 5 seconds and a hard commit every minute.
I was wondering if someone might have some insight about this?
I don't think it is related to merges since I see merger threads kicking in after 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you should check the usual suspects:

1. There is a problem with your Java (or whatever language you are using) application that you're using to index. If that's the case please specify the implementation details and I will provide more guidelines;
2. You're [NRT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching) cache fills up after 20 minutes and the hard commit doesn't happen quickly enough. In order to check this option,  please set the maximum number of documents to index before writing the docs from cache to the disc in the following way: `<autoCommit> <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs></autoCommit>` in case this is the issue then you can tune up the autocommit or the NRT cache management.

Comment: Thanks, but the indexing problem isn't the problem and I've added more info about autoCommit which rule it out too. @AR1

Comment: I see. Why do you have hard commit so often? I would advise to add a hard commit per max number of docs and per time,  let's say 10 minutes so you will reload the searcher just when needed. I am still thinking that tuning your throttling up would solve your issue.  What happens if you increase the heap on the machine where Solr is deployed??? I would think that the 20 min time would increase.

Comment: This is a real time system so I need to show arrived docs in few seconds from their arrival. I can reduce the hard commit but will it help with soft commit every 5 seconds?
I'm running with 14GB heap so memory isn't an issue here (I think) @AR1

Comment: Hard and soft commits are all about visibility, see this (https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/) good article about it. So,  if you have soft commits that will be enough. The fact that you have 14 gb doesn't necessarily mean that they're all allocated to Solr as you probably have other stuff on that machine.